# Setup of Whiteoctober-Swiftmailer-Bundle

Tags: database, symfony, entity, bundle, swiftmailer

I'd like to user the whiteoctober bundle for spooling my emails via my database. I followed the installation so far but am now stuck at the setup for the email entity itself (I know..)

So they provide this EmailInterface (https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberSwiftMailerDBBundle/blob/master/EmailInterface.php) which should be implemented in my own email entity. The documentation says:

> You will need to create an entity that can be persisted and that extends from the EmailInterface interface in the bundle. At the
>   moment, the bundle expects a property to be available on your entity
>   called 'status', since this field is queried.
>
> Once you have your entity all set up, use the full namespaced path in
>   your config.yml configuration as detailed above.

I have the following needs:

- an email is sent to multiple users due to different actions happening
  in the application. The email however should be sent **seperately**
  so that there is only one user in the "To" field
- a user should be able to receive emails (probably one or two email each day) --> it might happen, though, that the user gets assigned to several emails but he still should be added to the database only once!

other than that, the bundle provides message, status and environment as properties and I'm - to be honest- not 100% sure how to implement them..

So here is what I did so far:

```
   <?php

namespace NewsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use WhiteOctober\SwiftMailerDBBundle\EmailInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="news_email")
 */
class Email implements EmailInterface
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="spooledEmail", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     */
    protected $whereTo;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="subject")
    */
    protected $subject;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="text", name="message")
    */
    protected $message;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="status")
    */
    protected $status;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="environment")
    */
    protected $environment;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    /**
     * @param $message string Serialized \Swift_Mime_Message
     */
    public function setMessage($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * @param $status string
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEnvironment()
    {
        return $this->environment;
    }

    /**
     * @param $environment string
     */
    public function setEnvironment($environment)
    {
        $this->environment = $environment;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

So I set this up and updated the database. But how am I actually using the bundle now? how do I send emails etc.? I feel like the documentation doesn't really provide sufficient infos for non-pros.

Comment: Why not default spooling functionality of symfony ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid When using the default spooling I didn't figure out how to add a user to the receipients only if he's not in there yet.. so a user would get multiple emails a day and that's not what I want..

Comment: see my answer, the error you are getting has nothing to do with your bundle, it's simple the wrong Symfony command :)

Comment: great thanks! My only concern now is, how do I get them into my database? would I have to override the Service for that bundle?

Answer (score 0):

The command your are probably looking for is

```
doctrine:generate:entities NewsBundle:Email
```

to generate the getters & setters (note the `entities` instead of `entity`).
Hope it helps

Comment: thanks Florent, I'm still not sure whether I set everything up correctly.. (e.g. the $whereTo property --> mappedBy, what kind of relationship etc.) or  all the other properties.. that was the initial thought of my question :)

Comment: This is a more general question where you need to look at the docs for linked entities :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the docs, you would need to update your database schema and then configure swiftmail to use it:

```
# app/config/config.yml

white_october_swift_mailer_db:
    keep_sent_messages: true
```

Did you make any tests to see if it works ?

Comment: Hi, yes everything is working fine, I sent up the database and the emails get stored in there, but my question about how to set up the entity is not answered yet. I looked in the documentation but I can\t really figure out how to set it up the best way. That's why I was asking for advise, to see how experienced people would set the entity up and link it to the user entity etc.. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: My biggest issue is actually to figure out how to add one recipient only once to the database. but since there is no 'whereTo' column I can't really check on that. That's why I wanted to set it up by myself but I did it wrong i guess..

Comment: You want to store the user _entities_ that are supposed to receive the email ? Or simply the email adresses ?

Comment: Hm I'm not sure what the best way is. I think I want to store the users that are supposed to receive the email because then everytime a new email is generated I want to check if a user is already in that database table so he wouldn't be added more than one time..

Comment: Are you talking about transactional emails (like "Your order is confirmed") ok marketing emails (like a newsletter) ? Because I don't understand why you would check if a user has received an email. You either send it (and spool for as much time as you want) or don't. I don't see the reason why you should have to check

Comment: It's more like an *update* email. So our application sends out a generic email twice a day saying like "Something happened blabla check it out..." (there are several actions that result in an email generation)
So whenever that "something" affects an user, he is added to the 'recipients' of that email. But it might be that there happen multiple things that affect one single user, the generic email should still be sent out only one time, otherwise that user would get an email saying 'something happened blablabla' 10 times..
that's why I want to check if a user is already in the table :)

Comment: Ok I understand better your problematic. Setting up a OneToMany from Email to User seems okay, then you can check if a user is already on it, and as long as you flush your emails daily you should be ok.

Comment: great thanks! My only concern now is, how do I get them into my database? would I have to override the Service for that bundle? Because currently, I have that **whereTo** column in my user table and it's always null..

Comment: in the service, there is this **queue Message** function: 
    public function queueMessage(\Swift_Mime_Message $message)
    {
        ->setMessage(serialize($message));
        ->setStatus(EmailInterface::STATUS_READY);
        ->setEnvironment($this->environment);
        persist($mailObject);
        flush();

        return true;
    }
and I would think, that I'd have to at a **setWhereTo()** within that function. but I don't know how to access the setTo() function from the swiftmailer bundle..